# Opening HTML microsite from Sitecore Media Library v9.1.1

Tags: azure, media-library, paas

Looking for settings to open microsite uploaded to the media library in the browser.

In the past, we would take an Adobe Captivate HTML export load it into a folder in the media library, and run the .html from the folder eg. http://website.com/-/media/elearn/index.html. When we upload the same directory structure to our new site in azure using 9.1.1 the file downloads rather than running the site in the browser as it does on 7.2.

This worked well on 7.2 but seems to not work in 9.1.1 any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you please add details about what your process looked like on the older version and what you see now? Screenshots would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Don't upload that to the media library - create a folder in your instance and add that folder to the `IgnoreUrlPrefixes` setting in the Sitecore settings config.

Just make sure that IIS is configured to serve up static html files and you should be good to go.

Putting those files in the media library creates un-necessary load on the Sitecore instance.